# xfce4-indicator-plugin shows "No indicators"

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I was getting issues with duplicate application indicators in my top panel in Xfce. I was instructed to remove `indicator-applications` to fix the problem, but now xfce4-indicator-plugin is showing a "No indicators" message in the panel which is unnecessarily taking up space. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be due to this bug: [Long message when all indicators are hidden](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-indicator-plugin/+bug/1760955).

Evidently xfce4-indicator-plugin will show this message whenever no packages are installed that make use of it. In my case I hit the bug after uninstalling `indicator-messages`, which comes preinstalled with Xubuntu 18.04 but I didn't want, so I uninstalled `xfce4-indicator-plugin` and restarted the panel:

```
sudo apt remove xfce4-indicator-plugin
xfce4-panel -r
```

A couple alternative solutions:

- Remove Indicator Plugin from the panel

  Right-click in the panel > *Panel* > *Panel Preferences* > *Items* > select *Indicator Plugin* > *Remove*
- Or install at least one package which uses xfce4-indicator-plugin, for example:

  - indicator-application
  - indicator-messages
  - indicator-power
  - indicator-printers
  - indicator-sound

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-indicator-plugin/+bug/1801724/comments/7

Comment: in my case, uninstalling and installing back did the trick